# Failed to execute maven project

Tags: java, maven, solr

I'm doing a program using solr and when i tried to run my project i got the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) on project ri_t3: Command execution failed. Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>ri_t3</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>ri_t3</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
        <artifactId>solr-commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
           <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
           <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
           <version>4.10.2</version>
           <type>jar</type>
           <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
           <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
           <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
           <version>4.10.2</version>
           <type>jar</type>
           <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
           <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
           <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
           <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The main project is basically a call to the SolrServer and adding fields to the HttpSolrServer. 
I don't know if the problem is with pom.xml or with another thing. Can you help me?

Comment: The problem is located here: ` Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) ` which means the process which is started by exec-maven-plugin failed somehow. It might help if you post the whole error output. Furthermore show the complete configuration in pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please say how exactly are "running" the application ? I only see war , dependency and compiler plugins.

To package your app, you may want to run

```
mvn clean package
```

This should give you a war file that can be deployed to a servlet container. If you want to execute the application using maven, you may want to use [maven tomcat plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/)